# How to make ESLint ignore class names and methods from other files?

Tags: javascript, class, methods, eslint, ecmascript-5

This has probably been asked before, but I don't really know how to search for it so if it has, I am really sorry.

Say I have a file called **a.js** that has a class called `Navigation` in it, then in **b.js** I call that with a method inside the class called `getView()`;

**a.js**

```
Navigation.prototype.getView = function getView(id) {
   return this.views[id]; 
};
```

**b.js**

```
var currentView = Navigation.getView(id);
```

How would I go about tell ESLint that Navigation should be ignred from the no-undef rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the [globals](http://jshint.com/docs/) comment inside the file you want to ignore it.

```
/* globals MY_GLOBAL */
```

Comment: Why a comment? This is what eslint configuration is for.

Comment: I also noticed that I can just include this in the configuration file. Either way, it's still really helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

ESLint lints each file in isolation, so it will not resolve identifiers defined in other files. The [`/* exported ... */` comment](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#exported) and [globals](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals) allow you to inform ESLint of dependencies in other files.

> Note that `/* exported */` has no effect for any of the following:
>
> - when the environment is `node` or `commonjs`
> - when `parserOptions.sourceType` is `module`
> - when `ecmaFeatures.globalReturn` is `true`